# Exporting android project to jar (that includes other jars)

Tags: java, android, jar

I've written a Android Game Engine library and would like to export it to a jar file. I've tried to do this with the following:

> export > Jar File > Finish

As soon as I add the jar to the build path of another Android project, I get a little box in my code saying:

> The type foo cannot be resolved. It is indirectly
>   referenced from required .class files

I believe this is because my Game Engine library includes other libraries in forms of jars.

How can I add those jar files to my Game Engine jar file?

Answer (score 0):

You can decompile the other jar file using [JDui](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui), take what you need, and add it to your library. It all depends on how big is what you need..

Also, check whether you are using [proguard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) in the export. You would have to be careful on how to configure it.

Comment: Isn't there a way to just include the external jar in my jar that I create?

Answer (score 0):

I assuming you are using Eclipse. You also need to use Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries->Add Jar button to add your jar file to the target project

Comment: I've done this, yet when I export, they are not contained in the jar.

Comment: jar file is like zip file. You can unzip it to see if the corresponding .class file exists